# Error when try to initiate a class with vector<int> in a constructor

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, compiler-errors

Consider a following code:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;    
class DummyClass
{
public:
    DummyClass(){};
    DummyClass( int x ){}
    DummyClass (vector<int> array){}
};
int main()
{
    DummyClass(); // compiles
    DummyClass(5); // compiles
    vector<int> array;
    DummyClass obj = DummyClass( array );//compiles
    //DummyClass( array );// doesn't compile

}
```

Why the last line can't be compiled? error: Redefinition of 'array' with a different type: 'DummyClass' vs 'vector'

Comment: You are going to the edge of what your compiler allows as "valid" code, however only one of those definitions is of a form you should be using.

Comment: Because `DummyClass(array);`, as the compiler says, is a declaration with syntax that came from C and no code I have come across uses intentionally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the grammar, the last example that fails to compile is the same as `DummyClass array;` which re-declares the variable `array`. I think you meant `DummyClass obj2(array);`

Comment: or `DummyClass{array};`